# index indirect.ext match formula

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am using this formula below. It does work, but unfortunately once the match has found I do not get the proper column result back. I would expect the information out of column E, but I get the cell info back of another column. So what do I need to do in order to get always the results back of column E?

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT.EXT("'"&BO13&"
["&BO17&"]"&BO18&"'!"&BU5),MATCH(A75,INDIRECT.EXT("'"&BO13&"
["&BO17&"]"&BO18&"'!"&BU7),0),MATCH(AA75,INDIRECT.EXT("'"&BO13&"
["&BO17&"]"&BO18&"'!"&BU8),0))
```

- BO13 = Path
- BO17 = Filename.xlsx
- BO18 = SheetName
- BU5 = $E$3:$E$5 --> lookup range
- BU7 = $B$2:$B$5 --> including a certain name
- BU8 = $C$2:$C$5 --> including a certain number
- A75 = lookup value which is a name
- AA75 = lookup value which is a number

Comment: I'm confused, you say that it works but then you say it is not giving you the proper result. What do you mean?

Comment: You should post this as the answer to your question instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in case of similar issues. 
INDEX(INDIRECT.EXT("'"&BO13&"["&BO17&"]"&BO18&"'!"&BU5),MATCH(1,(INDIRECT.EXT("'"&BO13&"["&BO17&"]"&BO18&"'!"&BU7)=A75)*(INDIRECT.EXT("'"&BO13&"["&BO17&"]"&BO18&"'!"&BU8)=AA75),0))