# index indirect.ext match formula - falling at last hurdle

Tags: excel

I'm using an INDEX MATCH function to pull seasonal rainfall for ~200 field sites from weather station data into one summary file.

Each weather station is in a different excel file.

Different field sites need data from the weather station closest to them.

I can do it successfully one weather station at a time using the following formula:

```
=INDEX('PATH\BB.xlsx'!rain,(MATCH($I$4&$I$5,PATH\BB.xlsx'!year&'PATH\BB.xlsx'!season,0)))
```

where

•   PATH = file location (I can type this out as it’s always the same)

•   BB.xlsx = Filename.xlsx

•   rain, year and season are named ranges in the weather station workbooks

•   $I$4 = cell containing the lookup value for year

•   $I$5 = cell containing the lookup value for season

However, this means manually changing the filename in the formula for each field site.

**I'm therefore trying to write one formula that will automatically go to the correct weather station file to find the correct rainfall value.**

I found out about the MOREFUNC add-in from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811398/refer-to-excel-workbook-by-path-based-on-cell-value-data) post and I then based my formula on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035229/index-indirect-ext-match-formula) post.

This is my formula:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT.EXT("'PATH["&$F8&"]seasonaldata'!"&$K$3),MATCH(1,(INDIRECT.EXT("'PATH["&$F8&"]seasonaldata'!"&$K$5)=I5)*(INDIRECT.EXT("'PATH["&$F8&"]seasonaldata'!"&$K$4)=I4),0))
```

where

•   PATH = file location (I can type this out as it’s always the same)

•   $F8 = Filename.xlsx (this is the name of the workbook I want to go to)

•   seasonaldata = sheet name

•   $K$3 = lookup range (in fact K3 is a cell containing the word ‘rain’, which is the name of the lookup range in the weather station files)

•   $K$5 = --> including a certain season (i.e. cell K5 contains the name of a range where excel should look for the relevant season)

•   $K$4 = --> including a certain year (i.e. cell K4 contains the name of a range where excel should look for the relevant year)

•   I5 = cell containing one of the lookup values, which is a name (a season, i.e. winter)

•   I4 = cell containing the other lookup value, which is a number (a year, i.e. 2013)

The formula works until the very last part,

```
'PATH["&$F8&"]seasonaldata'!"&$K$4)=I4
```

It finds the years and correctly identifies the year I've specified in cell I4, but then returns all FALSE values, i.e. it isn't matching the value I specify in cell I4 with the values it's found in the 'year' range.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out myself - here's the answer in case it can be of any use to anyone in the future:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT.EXT("'PATH ["&$F8&"]seasonaldata'!"&$K$3),(MATCH($I$4&$I$5,(INDIRECT.EXT("'PATH["&$F8&"]seasonaldata'!"&$K$4))&(INDIRECT.EXT("'PATH["&$F8&"]seasonaldata'!"&$K$5)),0)))
```